# SQL IN operator in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have two tables of devices, my table 1 and table 2. I need to get all the models that has band (in table). Looking for ways on to execute this in sql bigquery. Thanks for the answer

[image]

Table 2

| model | band |
| --- | --- |
| SS1805 | CA_1A-40A,CA_1A-1A-3A,CA_12 |
| KA1935 | CA_3A-40A,CA_12 |
| L-01K | CA_1A-1A-3A, CA_3A-40A,CA_1A-40A |

Expected Output

| band | model | place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CA_1A-40A | SS1805,L-01K | aaa |
| CA_3A-40A | KA1935,L-01K | aaa |
| CA_1A-1A-3A | SS1805,L-01K | aaa |

Comment: You will likely want to take a look at the SPLIT() function, which breaks out those comma-separated values into an array that can then be more easily queried on.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
SELECT t1.band, STRING_AGG(model) AS model, place
FROM table2 t2, UNNEST(SPLIT(t2.band)) x
JOIN table1 t1
ON t1.band = TRIM(x)
GROUP BY band, place
```

If applied to sample data in your question -output is

[image]

Comment: thanks Mikhail this answers my concern, though I'm looking a work around on how to get let say the unique top 10 of the device model